# Cygwin isn't using the version of PHP i'd expect it to

Tags: php, bash, windows-7, cygwin, windows-console

For a number of reasons (laziness among them), I have a few different versions of php installed on my computer.  If I do `php -v` in my Windows Console, it shows the version of php I'd expect.  However, if I do `php -v` in my Cygwin terminal, I get a different version.

How can I tell Cygwin to use the version I want it to?  Currently PATH is pointed to the correct version.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What path did you set for PHP in `.bashrc` for cygwin? Did you remember that your Windows C drive is mounted to `/cygdrive/c/`:

`export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php` and not `export PATH=$PATH:\xampp\php`

Comment: if I `printenv PATH`, it shows as `/cygdrive/c/PHP`, which is the path that my windows console is looking in for the 'correct' one.

Comment: I didn't even think about adding an alias to PHP, I assumed that bash would read the path first and look along that path for php.  I added an alias to point the one I wanted, and now that seems to work.  I guess my question may have changed to, 'Why isn't cygwin looking along the PATH for the PHP executable?'